# Atmega32A фиюзы

Tags: avr, atmega

Имею Atmega32A и кварц на 16МГц, с конденсаторами на 22pF
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно выставить фьюзы, чтобы МК работал от внешнего кварца. Пользуюсь этим сайтом http://homes-smart.ru/fusecalc/?prog=avrstudio&part=ATmega32A

Будет ли работать МК при выставлении `0xFF LOW` и `0xD8 HIGH`? Это фьюзы Arduino Leonardo

Comment: имхо, лучше спросить здесь https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: спасибо, попробую https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/76092/atmega32a-fuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKOPT нужно включить, даже если нет внешнего генератора, устойчивость будет выше.
CKSEL3…0 = 1111 для генераторов больше 8 МГц.

> Будет ли работать МК при выставлении 0xFF LOW и 0xD8 HIGH?

В Proteus работает. Попробуйте вот эту софтину https://www.mikroe.com/mikroc-avr 
Её легко найти в сети и она сигналит, если фьюзы выставлены некорректно от слова совсем.

Answer (score 1):

В общем моя ошибка в том, что я первый раз установил `0xFB LOW` и `0xD8 HIGH`. Мне показалось, что это не должно было вывести МК из строя. Но я заблуждался. Прошил `0xFF LOW` и `0xD8 HIGH` - работает как надо.